# apiplatform can't access public resources

Tags: resources, api-platform.com

My problem is simple, I just installed apiplatform with jwt authentification. Everything works perfectly on my local machine but when I try to deploy it on my server and I try to load the "api/docs" page, I get a 404 on every resources from the public folder "public/bundles/apiplatform".

I don't use docker at all (and I have no intention to), my question is simple :

why it does not include the public folder from apiplatformbundle?

What could be the solution to include it ?

Is there any configuration to deal with inside the api_platform.yml ?

I am completely stuck right now, any advice would be really helpful, thanks :)

`docs:9 GET http://{myUrl}/bundles/apiplatform/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

`docs:8 GET http://{myUrl}/bundles/apiplatform/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

etc...

Comment: Do you use symfony cli to start the server or do you have something like a load balancer or api gateway in between?

Comment: Did you install the assets ?

Answer (score 1):

Please anyone ? Still don't get anything on it. It would be very helpful because actually the documentation can't be access by the front-end's part to access the API.

Comment: Maybe you nood to do bin/console assets:install? [more info](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command)

Comment: No, I have done it, it doesn't change anything

Comment: @MetaClass you made my day, bin/console assets:install worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I got it !

That's not easy because no errors are shown !

before, I was using

> use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

But now, you have to use in Apilatform 2.7 and further :

> use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;